# Did sage Narada call sage Durvasa a Donkey?

Tags: scripture, rishi, narada

Many [sites](http://www.bhagavatam-katha.com/narada-muni-story-learning-should-not-be-only-book-based/) claim that sage Durvasa was called a donkey by Sage Narada  as his Knowledge was only book based.

**MY QUESTION :**

- Is it true that Sage Durvasa was called Donkey by sage Narada?

Comment: Shakti - is it necessary to explore obscure (and likely untrue) stories that disparage rishis? What does knowing the answer to this question accomplish- for you or anyone else?

Answer (score 3):

The story is described by the Advaita philosopher Vidyaranya in [this excerpt](https://ia902605.us.archive.org/BookReader/BookReaderImages.php?zip=/14/items/jivanmuktiviveka00madhiala/jivanmuktiviveka00madhiala_jp2.zip&file=jivanmuktiviveka00madhiala_jp2/jivanmuktiviveka00madhiala_0084.jp2&scale=4&rotate=0) from his Jivanmukti Viveka, in the context of describing different kinds of Shastra Vasana:

> Addiction to many subjects of study is similarly of the nature of impure Vasana, inasmuch as it is not the last aim of existence. This is seen in the Kavasheya-Gita. A sage by name Durvasas came with a cart-load of Shastra-books to pay his respects to the god Mahadeva. In the learned assembly of that god, Narada aimed a joke at him in the parable of the ass carrying a load on his back; whereupon he was fired with such anger as led him to throw away all his books in the ocean. The god Mahadeva thereafter initiated him into the mystery of Self-knowledge; for, Self-knowledge never comes from the study of books, to him who has not acquired the faculty of intro-vision nor the favor of a competent teacher.

He says it comes from the Kavasheya Gita, a text I had never heard of before, but [this web page](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_giitaa/doc_giitaa.html) says that it's a text "[a]scribed to Brahma Purana, but not found in it".  Perhaps the Kavasheya Gita is only found in some manuscripts of the Brahma Purana.  Also, [this web page](https://www.kamakotimandali.com/misc/gorakshaworks.html) says that the Kavasheya Gita is quoted in a Nath text called the Goraksha Samhita.  In any case, I assume the name "Kavasheya" is connected to Tura Kavasheya, the priest of Arjuna's great-grandson Janamejaya.

Comment: looks like interpolated story..

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Well, without examining the Kavasheya Gita it's hard to reach that sort of a conclusion.  By default we should accept a putative scriptural passage as valid.

Comment: Any sanskrit book is not scripture. Further, kavasheya is not a famous one. But yes its individual's choice.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Well, it's sounds pretty likely to be a scripture if it's cited by both Vidyaranya and by Gorakshanath.  And it seems to be part of the Brahma Purana.

Comment: Wow I can't believe that 1. Narada, an exalted devotee called Durvasa a donkey and 2. There existed books in those days of oral recitation.

Comment: In the Sanatsujatiya (Mahabharata) Bhashya of Shankaracharya, I have so far seen two quotes from the Kavasheya Gita, mentioning once that it is part of Brahmanda Purana. Shankara cites a few verses from that source.  See last line here: https://ia800706.us.archive.org/BookReader/BookReaderImages.php?zip=/30/items/minorworksofsris015038mbp/minorworksofsris015038mbp_tif.zip&file=minorworksofsris015038mbp_tif/minorworksofsris015038mbp_0453.tif&id=minorworksofsris015038mbp&scale=4&rotate=0      It simply says तथा चोक्तं ब्राह्मे.. But in another pdf I have, the full verse is cited.

Comment: In the very next page https://ia800706.us.archive.org/BookReader/BookReaderImages.php?zip=/30/items/minorworksofsris015038mbp/minorworksofsris015038mbp_tif.zip&file=minorworksofsris015038mbp_tif/minorworksofsris015038mbp_0454.tif&id=minorworksofsris015038mbp&scale=4&rotate=0     one can see 'तथा च कावषेयगीतासु - आत्मज्ञः शोकसन्तीर्णो न बिभेति कुतश्चनेति |  Here too, in the other pdf I have, a whole four verses are cited. I now conclude that the two editions are diff and the one in archive is not have the full quotes.